# Ignore position of selector in a CSS precompiler hierarchy

Tags: sass, less, stylus

Say I have:

```
.checkout-form-container {
    // styles

    .checkout-radio-buttons {
         // styles
    }
}
```

(I know this might be a reach, but) Is there any way to tell .checkout-radio-buttons to ignore it's position in the hierarchy and compile to:

```
.checkout-form-container {
     // styles
}        
.checkout-radio-buttons {
     // styles
}
```

Why?

Precompiler nested hierarchies are great for promoting the understandability of the code.  However, in terms of performance, using only top level selectors is faster than using more complex selection patterns.

See: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

> Selectors have an inherent efficiency, and to quote Steve Souders, the
>   order of more to less efficient CSS selectors goes thus:
>
> - ID, e.g. #header
> - Class, e.g. .promo
> - Type, e.g. div
> - Adjacent sibling, e.g. h2 + p
> - Child, e.g. li > ul
> - Descendant, e.g. ul a
> - Universal, i.e. *
> - Attribute, e.g. [type="text"]
> - Pseudo-classes/-elements, e.g. a:hover

Instead you should write unique class names (or ids for non-repeated elements) in your css if you want performance to be better (even if only slightly).

Therefore, being able to write in a nested selection pattern would improve readability of code while maintaining the higher performance of top level selectors.

My proposed solution would necessitate a top level escape character e.g. !

```
.checkout-form-container {
    // styles

    !.checkout-radio-buttons {
         // styles
    }
}
```

which would take the selector out of its position in the hierarchy.  Is making a value proposition to the creators of a technology (in this case: less, sass, and stylus) against the rules of Stack Overflow?

Comment: It seems like it would be confusing if the code were organized one way but compiled to something else.

Comment: [This is an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In SASS you can use `at-root()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is no.

Currently there are no ways with less.js to declare selectors in a hierarchy, but ignore their position in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [nesting](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules).

A nested selectors compiles into its descendant combinators:

```
.parent {
  .child {
  }
}
```

outputs:

```
.parent .child {}
```

Alternatively you could use the [extend feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature):

```
.selector1 { //styles }
.selector2:extend(.selector1) {}
```

outputs:

```
.selector1,
.selector2 {
 // styles
}
```

[Namespace](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors) can be used to group your mixins, for organizational purposes.

```
#checkout {
 .form-container() { //styles}
}

//caller:
div.form-container {
#checkout > .form-container;
}
```

outputs:

```
div.form-container {
//styles
}
```

Your question suggest that your are looking for namespaces whilst your class names suggest that your are looking for nesting.

Notice that the same seems to be true for SASS and Stylus.